# If I replay a level in Donkey Kong Country Returns do I have to collect KONG again?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

As far as I can tell, if I collect specific puzzle pieces in a given level in *Donkey Kong Country Returns* for Nintendo Wii, when I play that level again I do not have to collect those same puzzle pieces again -- the show somewhat transparent to indicate I already got them. (I think I'm right here -- please correct me if I'm wrong!)

If I play a given level and I collect all the `K` `O` `N` `G` letters, and I replay that level later, do I have to collect the `K` `O` `N` `G` letters a second time? (There seems to be no indication I can see that I collected them before...)

Comment: What's the best tag to use for something like this? `[bonus]`? Doesn't seem to be quite accurate...

Comment: Just the game is mostly sufficient for this, I would imagine. The concept isn't so strong as to require a tag of its own, at this point. ♪

Comment: @Grace Thanks! I'm a bit of a tag fanatic on SO, in case it wasn't clear ;-)

Comment: [collectibles], I should think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**  You only have to collect all the KONG letters and finish a level **once** to earn that level's  KONG star.  On subsequent plays of a level, you can ignore the letters.  Once you collect all the KONG letters in all the levels of an area/world, you'll unlock a special bonus temple for that area.

When trying to find all the KONG letters, you lose any collected letters since the last checkpoint each time you die.  This can get rather frustrating on mine cart levels where you have to time your jumps perfectly.

Fortunately, this is not true of the puzzle pieces.  Once collected, you keep those permanently, even if you die.

In all cases, if you quit, or lose all your lives, before finishing a level, you lose all items you collect, letters and puzzle pieces.

Comment: Do note: if you get a gameover before completing the level, you must recollect any found puzzle pieces. Also, why is this game so *hard*? :(

Comment: It would be easier with a button control for rolling/slamming as opposed to shake controls.  There's always an element of innacurracy with those, I find.

Comment: You do need to collect them again in Mirror Mode for 200%, though.